# REACT- Popover doesn't display my json content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, popover

In `menu/` the name of my invited people are not diplayed there is only the `InfoIcon` in the Cell. I want to create a `Popover`, when you click on the `InfoIcon`, you get all the info of the invited people(name and location).

```
export default function Display() {
  const { dishes } = JsonData;
  const [anchor, setAnchor] = useState(null);
  const openPopover = (event) => {
    setAnchor(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const data = useMemo(
    () => [
     ...
      {
        //Problem: participants not displayed and click not working
        Header: "Invited",
        id: "invited",
        accessor: (row) => row.invited.map(({ name }) => name).join(", "),
        Cell: (props) => (
          <div>
            <InfoIcon />
            <Popover
              open={Boolean(anchor)}
              anchorEl={anchor}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "left"
              }}
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: "bottom",
                horizontal: "right"
              }}
            >
              <Typography variant="h1">{props.participants}</Typography>
            </Popover>
          </div>
        )
      },
    ],
    []
  );

  return (
    <Table
      data={dishes}
      columns={data}         
    />
  );
}
```

Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-z37eu1?file=/src/Display.jsx)

Comment: any specific reason you are not using Tooltip?

Comment: Hi, I've tried but doesn't seem working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to saving the clicked element into state so the `Popover` component has an element ref it needs to also store in state which specific row's participants to render into the popover. Currently the code is using a singular boolean value for ***all*** the popovers. Use the `row.id` to open a specific popover.

Don't forget to add the "anchor" state to the dependency array so the popover gets the latest state.

```
function Display() {
  const { menus } = JsonData;

  const [anchorId, setAnchorId] = useState(null);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const openPopover = id => (event) => {
    setAnchorId(id);
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorId(null);
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const data = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Id",
        accessor: (row) => row.id
      },
      {
        Header: "Invited",
        id: "invited",
        accessor: (row) => row.invited,
        Cell: (props) => (
          <div>
            {props.value.map(({ name }) => name).join(", ")}
            <InfoIcon onClick={openPopover(props.row.id)} />
            <Popover
              open={anchorId === props.row.id}
              onClose={handleClose}
              anchorEl={anchorEl}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "left"
              }}
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: "bottom",
                horizontal: "right"
              }}
            >
              <Typography variant="h6">
                {props.value.map(({ name, location }) => (
                  <div key={name}>
                    <p>{name}</p>
                    <p>Location: {location}</p>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </Typography>
            </Popover>
          </div>
        )
      },
      {
        Header: "Title",
        accessor: (row) => ({ title: row.title, id: row.id }),
        Cell: ({ value }) => (
          <Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${value.id}` }}>{value.title}</Link>
        )
      }
    ],
    [anchorEl, anchorId]
  );

  const initialState = {
    sortBy: [
      { desc: false, id: "id" },
      { desc: false, id: "invited" },
      { desc: false, id: "title" }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <Table
      data={menus}
      columns={data}
      initialState={initialState}
      withCellBorder
      withRowBorder
      withSorting
      withPagination
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-popover-doesnt-display-my-json-content]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, it is not exactly what I wanted, I've added an image in my question to get the idea

Comment: @Zokulko I see, I've updated answer and linked codesandbox.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to do the same with `OverlayTrigger` and  `Tooltip` from `react-bootstrap` (I've already tried but not working ) please?

Comment: With Material-UI, in order to style the Components, we need to use inline-styling only. Is it the same if I use `Tooltip`? Btw I don't know why I'm not able to pop up next  to the related `InfoIcon`. So I'm trying to do the same with `Tooltip` just to see and pratice a bit

Comment: I saw the docs and the popup appears next to the button with `mui` without using `style`...I don't know if there is a way to do so...

Comment: @Zokulko Sorry, was out for a few days. I do recall seeing a warning about positioning and assumed the table component was creating the issue. Do you have a sandbox with the tooltip and overlay implemented?

Comment: no worries ! I tried something else `MyPop` [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-z37eu1?file=/src/Display.jsx), as you said I think that it is the `Table` component the issue but it doesn't work yet ...